# Interview Follow-Up Email Etiquette

Tags: etiquette, email, interview

I am writing a follow-up thank-you email for a teaching position that I interviewed for at a place where I am an adjunct. If I have had a (good) idea based on something the committee discussed, can I include that in the email, or does it come off as over-eager and/or desperate?

For what it's worth, the committee did say to get in touch with them if I had any further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it good to share. It shows you are thoughtful and got something out of the discussion. But keep it short.